# conditional creating(populate) a column that will have to process the rows in the dataframe to match criterias

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a couple of datetime value columns and a few other categorical/continuous columns.
For ease of describing, I am uploading a snippet of the dataframe, Have also removed the actual date values to avoid clutter.

[image]

I am trying to create a column that will have to process the rows in the dataframe to match the criterias before coming to a decision of what to populate in this new column.

In this case:

If the SECTOR AND BASE value of a row match with the same values in some other row(s) 
AND
IF the END date of this/these preceeding (the row that has the SECTOR AND BASE equivalent to the row that is now found to have the same SECTOR AND BASE) rows matches the START date of the row thats at a later stage in the dataframe, then populate with 1, else 0.
So, essentially, am looking at something like this:

[image]

```
 BASE     SECTOR     START    END     CHECK
 S     DHHJJ    12/2/2018   13/3/2018   0
 B       DJH    12/3/2018   13/3/2018   0
 S      FHJDFJK 12/4/2018   13/3/2020   0
 B     FHJDG    12/5/2018   13/3/2021   0
 T       XYZ    23/03/2018  25/03/2018  1
 T      ABCD    12/1/2017   13/2/2017   0
 T      ABCD    1/2/2018    1/3/2018    1
 T      ABCD    1/3/2018    15/3/2018   1
 T       XYZ    12/1/2015   12/2/2015   0
 B       XYZ    15/5/2017   15/7/2017   1
 T       XYZ    12/2/2014   12/3/2014   0
 B       XYZ    15/7/2017   20/7/2017   0
 T     SFJUTEUI 12/2/2018   13/3/2018   0
 T      RUTI    12/3/2018   13/3/2019   0
 T      FDJTK   12/4/2018   13/3/2020   0
 B    FJURTUI   12/5/2018   13/3/2021   0
 T    RYURTI    12/6/2018   13/3/2022   0
 T     SFJUI    12/7/2018   13/3/2023   0
 T       XYZ    25/03/2018  30/03/2018  0
 T       XYZ    12/4/2018   12/4/2018   0
 T       XYZ    1/4/2016    1/5/2016    1
 T       XYZ    1/5/2016    5/5/2016    0
 T      ABCD    15/3/2018   31/3/2018   0
```

Adding the data with the exclusive amendment of BASE condition:

```
BASE    SECTOR  START       END       CHECK
   S    DHHJJ   12/2/2018   13/3/2018   0
   B    DJH    12/3/2018    13/3/2018   0
   S    FHJDFJK 12/4/2018   13/3/2020   0
   B    FHJDG   12/5/2018   13/3/2021   0
   T    XYZ 23/03/2018  25/03/2018  1
   T    ABCD    12/1/2017   13/2/2017   0
   B    ABCD    1/2/2018    1/3/2018    1
   T    ABCD    1/3/2018    15/3/2018   1
   T    XYZ    12/1/2015    12/2/2015   0
   B    XYZ    15/5/2017    15/7/2017   1
   T    XYZ    12/2/2014    12/3/2014   0
   T    XYZ    15/7/2017    20/7/2017   0
   T    SFJUTEUI    12/2/2018   13/3/2018   0
   T    RUTI    12/3/2018   13/3/2019   0
   T    FDJTK   12/4/2018   13/3/2020   0
   B    FJURTUI 12/5/2018   13/3/2021   0
   T    RYURTI  12/6/2018   13/3/2022   0
   T    SFJUI   12/7/2018   13/3/2023   0
   T    XYZ   25/03/2018    30/03/2018  0
   T    XYZ    12/4/2018    12/4/2018   0
   T    XYZ     1/4/2016    1/5/2016    1
   B    XYZ     1/5/2016    5/5/2016    0
   B    ABCD    15/3/2018   31/3/2018   0
```

Comment: Pictures are bad.  Please post real data.

Comment: Hi @piRSquared, the Real data can be termed a little sensitive.
Do you mean the pictures are bad resolution/clarity wise?

Comment: No, I mean for those of us who answer questions, it makes it many times easier to help if we have data to experiment with.  When you post a picture, my two choices are to transcribe the data (which I'm not going to do) or pass on answering it (which I will do).  However, all you have to do is [edit] the post and paste the same data you snapped a screenshot of and that would allow me to copy that same data and make a data frame out of it.  Then I could rapidly help you (as could others)

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Let me do that right away :)

Comment: Added the dates...Thanks @piRSquared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function with `groupby` for check membership and exlude rows with same `START` and `END` dates. For `0, 1` values convert boolean to integer.

```
df[['START','END']] = df[['START','END']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

def f(x):
    #test all start datetimes, order is not important
    x['Check1'] = (x['END'].isin(x['START']) & (x['END'] != x['START'])).astype(int)
    return x

df = df.groupby(['BASE','SECTOR']).apply(f)
print (df)
   BASE    SECTOR      START        END  CHECK  Check1
0     S     DHHJJ 2018-12-02 2018-03-13      0       0
1     B       DJH 2018-12-03 2018-03-13      0       0
2     S   FHJDFJK 2018-12-04 2020-03-13      0       0
3     B     FHJDG 2018-12-05 2021-03-13      0       0
4     T       XYZ 2018-03-23 2018-03-25      1       1
5     T      ABCD 2017-12-01 2017-02-13      0       0
6     T      ABCD 2018-01-02 2018-01-03      1       1
7     T      ABCD 2018-01-03 2018-03-15      1       1
8     T       XYZ 2015-12-01 2015-12-02      0       0
9     B       XYZ 2017-05-15 2017-07-15      1       1
10    T       XYZ 2014-12-02 2014-12-03      0       0
11    B       XYZ 2017-07-15 2017-07-20      0       0
12    T  SFJUTEUI 2018-12-02 2018-03-13      0       0
13    T      RUTI 2018-12-03 2019-03-13      0       0
14    T     FDJTK 2018-12-04 2020-03-13      0       0
15    B   FJURTUI 2018-12-05 2021-03-13      0       0
16    T    RYURTI 2018-12-06 2022-03-13      0       0
17    T     SFJUI 2018-12-07 2023-03-13      0       0
18    T       XYZ 2018-03-25 2018-03-30      0       0
19    T       XYZ 2018-12-04 2018-12-04      0       0
20    T       XYZ 2016-01-04 2016-01-05      1       1
21    T       XYZ 2016-01-05 2016-05-05      0       0
22    T      ABCD 2018-03-15 2018-03-31      0       0
```

If ordering of datetimes is important for check membership:

```
def f1(x):
    e = x['END']
    s = x['START']
    #for each start datetime test all next end datetimes
    m = {j[0]: (s.iloc[i+1:] == j[1]).any() for i,j in enumerate(e.items())}
    x['Check2'] = pd.Series(m).astype(int)
    return x

df = df.groupby(['BASE','SECTOR']).apply(f1)
print (df)
```

For better see difference one value was changed:

```
print (df.tail())
   BASE SECTOR       START         END  CHECK
18    T    XYZ  25/03/2018  30/03/2018      0
19    T    XYZ    5/5/2016   12/4/2018      0 <-changed value to 5/5/2016
20    T    XYZ    1/4/2016    1/5/2016      1
21    T    XYZ    1/5/2016    5/5/2016      0
22    T   ABCD   15/3/2018   31/3/2018      0


df = df.groupby(['BASE','SECTOR']).apply(f)
df = df.groupby(['BASE','SECTOR']).apply(f1)
print (df.tail())
   BASE SECTOR      START        END  CHECK  Check1  Check2
18    T    XYZ 2018-03-25 2018-03-30      0       0       0
19    T    XYZ 2016-05-05 2018-12-04      0       0       0
20    T    XYZ 2016-01-04 2016-01-05      1       1       1
21    T    XYZ 2016-01-05 2016-05-05      0       1       0
22    T   ABCD 2018-03-15 2018-03-31      0       0       0
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I'll try this out, And if i were to add one more condition to it such that,
The BASE may not be exactly same, but it can B or T if the preceeding match is B.

Comment: Hmmm, then it is more complicated... Btw, need first or second my solution?

Comment: Check1 (Not Check2) is the column that satisfies my requirement.

Comment: I believe adding the BASE condition on top of the above will require another function or a list which stores the possible vlaues of BASE for a given value of BASE
If BASE=='T' | 'B' & BASE=='B' (for the earlier row) & the Start == END (for the earlier row), then Check = 1

Comment: @asimo - Can you change data for new condition with expected output?

Comment: @thanks Jezrael , I have amended the question and have posted the output data.

Comment: So, essentially, a B can accept B as well as T as well as X in the next rows. 
a T can accept T as well as B as well as X in the next rows.
However, a B cannot accept S (not in the data posted, but I have it in my df), and vice versa

Comment: @asimo - so groups are not important? Or grouping by `SECTOR`?

Comment: Grouping by sector is still required.

Comment: So the way it goes is...first need to ensure that the sector is same and then if the base involved are only B, T or X  and the end date corresponds to becoming start date in order to qualify as 1

Comment: Sorry if I have made it complicated in putting this forward, am encountering some sort of brain freeze.

Comment: I got idea. Is not possible simple remove values with `S` only and change solution to `df = df.query("BASE != 'S'").groupby(['SECTOR']).apply(f)` ?

Comment: Actually S will have its own conditions...I need to also ensure that S goes with T or X in the same way as B goes with X or T

Comment: OK, so about `x['Check1'] = (x['END'].isin(x['START']) & x['BASE'].isin(['B','T','X'])& (x['END'] != x['START'])).astype(int)`

Comment: ...and `df.groupby(['SECTOR']).apply(f)` ?

Comment: Give me a few moments to try please

Comment: can I please revert to you by Monday on how it’s working

Comment: @asimo - sure, no problem. Nice weekend!

Comment: Thanks @jezrael 
It works, I split the dataframes based on the BASE values. 
Applied the function (that created unique check column in the two dataframes)
Merged the dataframes back appropriately.
Cheers jezrael

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Jezrael,
So just to summarise: Here is the solution:

```
merged_data_nB = merged_data[merged_data['BASE'] != 'B']    
merged_data_nS = merged_data[merged_data['BASE'] != 'S']   

def f_B(x):
x['Check_B'] =  (x['END'].isin(x['START']) & x['BASE'].isin(['B','T','X'])& (x['END'] != x['START'])).astype(int)                  
return x

def f_S(x):
x['Check_S'] =  (x['END'].isin(x['START']) & x['BASE'].isin(['S','T','X'])& (x['END'] != x['START'])).astype(int)                  
return x

abcd_B = merged_data_nS.groupby(['SECTOR']).apply(f_B)
abcd_S = merged_data_nB.groupby(['SECTOR']).apply(f_S)
result1 = abcd_B.join(abcd_S, how='outer', lsuffix='_B', rsuffix='_S')
```